# System limit for make parallelism

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to set a system limit on the number of `make` processes it automatically sets with `-j`? I've got a system which defaults to `-j8`, but there's not enough memory to handle that without swapping.

I'd like to set a system default of `-j4` if no specific number is provided.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything in the manual that indicates you can do this and I don't think you can override `-j` in `MAKEFLAGS` or anything like that.

You can, in newer versions of make at least, use the [`-l`/`--max-load` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel) to have make scale the number of jobs based on system load but that's not a memory limit.

The only thing I could think of to do this would be to wrap the `make` binary itself in a script of some sort that controlled the `-j` option passed to it (if any) and any value in `MAKEFLAGS` in the environment.